# How to change page location in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change my page location (link address). My blog page location is:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1336.
```

I want to change blog page location

`http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1336` to `http://localhost/wordpress/`

So if anyone visits my website then blog page show him as home page. So anyone can tell me how I can do this. Thanks

Comment: i don't understand, so you want to redirect all links to the homepage? that doesn't sound very good

Comment: No, I want to redirect only one page to home page. I want to create a option for user "Please select a page for home page". User selected page show as home page. Thanks for your reply

Comment: is this per user? or site wide. things change drastically depending on that. regardless, you can use a plugin, some action, or create a page template and set the header to site_url().

Comment: Only admin can select this option from theme option panel. If I create a page template then this page show it's own address (like http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1336). creating page template don't show as home page (http://localhost/wordpress/). I want to change page own location to home page location

Comment: why don't you just use the built-in method to set homepage? settings->reading

Comment: I see most of the popular theme like enfold use this option on his theme option panel. Can you give any reference or idea how can I use this option on my theme option panel. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your blog page as your homepage then go to Admin Panel >> Appearance >> Customize >> Static Front Page

Select Front page from here.

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to create this option in my theme option panel. Thanks